# MS Access linked sharepoint table - unable to update a value

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a 2010 sharepoint list.  It's linked to Microsoft Access as a linked table.  I'm trying to make some updates in Access.  The SP list has no lookup columns, all of the People-type fields are People Only (not People and Groups), there is no referential integrity set because there are no lookup columns, and absolutely none of the columns are required.  Also, there is no Validation set on any column in the List Settings.
I get the error:  "You cannot update this field because the value you're trying to apply is not valid or would break a data integrity rule. Please correct and try again"
The thing that's frustrating is, if I ADD records (using Access), I can do that, and then I can EDIT those records.  When I first add them, I don't include any People information (because it seems I cannot do that from Access) - I leave those columns blank.
If I THEN go, at that point, to my newly created records, in sharepoint online, and add some People information, and then go back to Access, suddenly I cannot do ANY update in ANY column - I get that error message.

Anyone know what this might be or what I am doing wrong?  I'm not even trying to update a People field in access at this point - I'm only trying to update fields I was easily able to update in Access a few minutes ago--just BEFORE I populated those People columns with data in SP online.

Comment: I have discovered a workaround.  I created a Sharepoint VIEW (that did NOT contain any People columns).  I then used Access VBA to link to the VIEW only - and then suddenly I was able to freely edit all of those other columns which I'm not able to if I link to the List.  I am a little new on Stack Overflow, so not sure if I should leave this question as-is, mark answered, or do something else.  Thanks for reading.

Comment: Could create an answer yourself and mark it accepted.